# Promise and Observable together in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am reading about Promise and Observable and I am not sure if my code is valid for angular2+

I am using Promise with new http client

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
      this.http
        .get('http://x.x.com/api/x/' + x + '/' + x + '/' + x + '', {
          headers: this.authenticationService.getAuthorizationHeader()
        })
        .subscribe(
          (data: any) => {
            resolve(data.map((row) => {
              return new Candlestick(row.time, row.open, row.high, row.low, row.close, row.volume)
            }));
          },
          (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            if (error.error instanceof Error) {
              console.log('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
            } else {
              console.log(`Backend returned code ${error.status}, body was: ${error.error}`);
            }

            return resolve();
          });
    });
```

Is this ok or bad example?

Answer (score 3):

Code looks okey but if your purpose is to use observable then you can use `toPromise`

```
this.http
.get('http://x.x.com/api/x/' + x + '/' + x + '/' + x + '', {
          headers: this.authenticationService.getAuthorizationHeader()
})
.toPromise()
.then()
```

Also in your code you are doing resolve() on error which is wrong to me, i would better call reject.

Your code would make more sense lets say if you want to do retries or any other cool things, but if you need Promise then use toPromise.

Comment: Thank you for your anser. You wrote retries? If I don't use retzries then I also don't need toPromise? And I don't need subscribe anymore?

Comment: @mbrc Yes, i do have in some of my codes, where http request has timeout and retries. Even I think architecturally using Observable for http is wrong and confusing, I am using it because its coming with Angular and as soon as you used to it you are good. So I would not use toPromise or promise at all. this is kind of trade off when you choose framework you need to should use dictated patterns :) this will save your project later when new devs join your team

Comment: @mbrc use only if there is reason :) not because you used to it or some companyX is doing that :)